# SwiftUI- force refresh of viewModel when database loaded inside this viewModel changes

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Complete SwiftUI beginner here.
I started to play with SwiftUI using Nick Sarno aka "Swiftful Thinking" project (https://github.com/SwiftfulThinking/SwiftfUI-Map-App-MVVM). This project is a Map app with NVMM structure. It consists of database of locations and shows them on user-friendly interface consisting of Map, locations list and detail view overlay. I really like the interface and smooth feeling of this app.

There is viewModel used as @EnvironmentObject in all child views (LocationsViewModel.swift). Inside this model the database consisting of array of structs (stored as static let in LocationsDataService.swift file) is initialized and loaded into variable called locations (line 35 of LocationsViewModel.swift).

```
init() {
    let locations = LocationsDataService.locations
    self.locations = locations
    self.mapLocation = locations.first!
    self.updateMapRegion(location: locations.first!)
}
```

I am trying to update the database with additional locations on the runtime, but I can't figure out how to reload views to show new data on the list of locations without app restart. From my complete beginner point of view LocationsViewModel is set as ObservableObject, so any change to it should force views observing it to redraw, but it is not occurring. I even tried to "re-init" the view model to once again load database into let, but no luck..

Can you advice and point me into right direction how to force app to refresh itself when Locations database is changed (either new locations are added or some are removed)?

**Edit - More details:**

I am updating LocationsDataService.locations from local JSON file which I create/update upon receiving it from my Apple Watch.
File is stored in AppSupportDirectory. If my JSON file is not empty and is correctly written, then its contents are decoded and loaded into LocationsViewModel().locations using below function:

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject{

    func LoadFromJson()  {
            do{
                let fileUrl = pathForAppSupportDirectoryAsUrl()?.appendingPathComponent("pinData.JSON")
                let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: (fileUrl)!)
                if !fileData.isEmpty {
                    let arrayOfPins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Location].self, from: fileData)
                    LocationsViewModel().locations = arrayOfPins
                }
                
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }

    func pathForAppSupportDirectoryAsUrl() -> URL?{
        var appSupportDirectory: URL?
        do{
            appSupportDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        }catch{
            print("problem!")
        }
        return appSupportDirectory
    }
}
```

LoadFromJson() is called after the file is successfully encoded and saved inside app support directory.
I know that writing to local file and then decoding it works, as my locations dataset is correctly updated if I kill the app and start it again.

Thank you so much

Karol

Comment: at the very least show us some basic code, where and how you update your `database` and `LocationsViewModel` with additional locations? Where do you expect the view with the new data to be updated.

Comment: I see where your troubles stem from.
In `DataManager` you have a nested `LocationsViewModel`  ObservableObject. This in itself can be problematic.
However, the worst is that you create a completly new `LocationsViewModel` that has no relations to any other `LocationsViewModel` where you have 
`LocationsViewModel().locations = arrayOfPins`.  
In other words, you need to have **only one source of truth** as you have 
in your `SwiftfulMapAppApp`, and pass this around to other views and problematically to your `DataManager`. Re-think your approach, and do not nest ObservableObjects

Comment: it's better to learn the View struct for the view data instead of trying to implement view model objects on top, you might get so far but will eventually run into issues. I recommend Apple tutorials those  mostly use the View struct hierarchy correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend separating `LocationsViewModel` from `DataManager` and just have `DataManager` return the decoded `Location` array:

```
final class DataManager {

    func loadLocationPinsFromJson() throws -> [Location]  {
        let fileUrl = pathForAppSupportDirectoryAsUrl()?.appendingPathComponent("pinData.JSON")
        let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: (fileUrl)!)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Location].self, from: fileData)
    }

    private func pathForAppSupportDirectoryAsUrl() -> URL? {
        try? FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    }
}
```

In `LocationsViewModel` you could initialize an instance of `DataManager` or pass in a shared instance and use it to load the `Location` array when `LocationsListView` appears:

```
final class LocationsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var locations = [Location]()
    private let dataManager = DataManager() // initialize here or pass in shared instance

    func loadLocations() {
        do {
            locations = try dataManager.loadLocationPinsFromJson()
        } catch {
            // handle loading error...
        }
    }
}
```

Here `LocationsListView` initializes `LocationsViewModel` as a `StateObject` and calls `viewModel.loadLocations` in the `onAppear` modifier:

```
struct LocationsListView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = LocationsViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Locations List Here (viewModel.locations)...")
            .onAppear(perform: viewModel.loadLocations)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain all that! I think I did all the changes you suggested to my code, however still no luck, LocationsListView does not get updated when I call loadFromJson function. I think reason for the problem may be hidden somewhere in LocationsDataService class where initial locations set is stored. It is declared as  static var, shouldn't it be @published var so its changes can be observed?

Comment: Now I that Locations does not have to be @published var. I think, that my problem originates from place where I call DataManager().loadFromJson(). Calling DataManager|() creates new instance of DataManager and LocationsViewModel() as it is declared there as let locationsViewModel = LocationsViewModel(). But how to access existing instance of DataManager from any child view of my app? for example I created NavigationLink which opens another simple view with button. How to call DataManager from my new view without creating new instances but rather accessing existing instance of DataManager?

Comment: @KarolB I see. Creating a new instance of DataManager is problematic. I have updated my answer based on this new information. It would probably be best to separate the view model from the process of fetching the data. I hope this helps.